# Cannot initialize module TreeWalker during the build in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, checkstyle

I'm performing Project-Clean... in Eclipse Mars and getting the following error

```
   Errors occurred during the build.
     Errors running builder 'Checkstyle Builder' on project 'MyProject'.
        cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate 
        'RedundantThrows' class, it is also not possible to instantiate it as 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.annotation.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.blocks.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.design.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.header.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.imports.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.indentation.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.metrics.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.modifier.RedundantThrows,
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.naming.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.regexp.RedundantThrows,
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.sizes.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.whitespace.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.filters.RedundantThrows, 
        com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.RedundantThrows. Please recheck that class name 
        is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short name usage 
        http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Packages. Please also recheck that 
        provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly.
```

The CheckStyle plugin version is 6.11.
Could you please help me figuring out what may cause this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *RedundantThrows* check [has been removed](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/473) from Checkstyle. Just remove the `<module>` entry for it from your *checkstyle.xml*.